# Copy bundle resources manually

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, webview, assets

I have a React Native project that renders a static HTML file in a webview, and that file is read locally from the device. Therefore I have to re-run the app from Xcode in order for my changes to the HTML file to appear in the app, which is quite time consuming.

Is it possible to run just the "copy bundle resources" step manually in order to get the static asset files moved to the device/simulator without making a complete Xcode build? That way it would be possible to just refresh the React Native app and see the changes I guess.

Comment: Great question, having same issue here!